# How to use 2 models in 1 View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Booking model and I create a list of all it's elements in the BookingController. There I managed to export the list as .json, however when I want to import a file I can't manage to use my custom validation to see if it's only .json. The problem is that in my Index for Booking I have a IEnumerable model for Booking and I use a BookingsUpload model to upload the file. So how can I access this BookingsUpload model inside the Index or how could i change it ? (could I combine what i do in BookingsUpload with my Booking model ?

Booking Model:

```
public class Booking
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ladestand")]
    [Range(0, 100)]
    public double chargeState { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Benötigte Fahrstrecke")]
    [Range(1, 1000)]
    public double distance { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Beginn")]
    public DateTime startTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Ende")]
    public DateTime endTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Anschlusstyp")]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(ConnectorType))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public ConnectorType connectorType { get; set; }
}

public class BookingList
        {
            public List<Booking> BookingListObj { get; set; }
        }
```

BookingsUpload Model:

```
public class BookingsUpload
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a file.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    [MaxFileSize(1024 * 1024)]
    [AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".json" })]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}
```

** NEW UPDATE **:
Now Controller doesn't work as intended. Cannot add elements to List (or maybe they are added just can't display it in the View not sure):
Controller:

```
public class BookingController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;
    private string bookingsKey = "bookingsList";
    public BookingController(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _cache = memoryCache;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Booking> bookigsList;
        _cache.TryGetValue<List<Booking>>(bookingsKey, out bookigsList);
        return View(bookigsList);
    }

    /* MVVC fucking failed :(
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        BookingList bookingsList;
        //_cache.TryGetValue(bookingsKey, out bookingList);

        bookingsList = new BookingList();
        bookingsList.BookingListObj = new List<Booking>();

        bookingsList.BookingListObj.Add(new Booking() { chargeState = 30, distance = 150, startTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 13, 13, 45, 0), endTime = new DateTime(2020, 8, 13, 17, 0, 0) });
        _cache.Set<List<Booking>>(bookingsKey, bookingsList.BookingListObj);

        BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel()
        {
            Bookings = bookingsList.BookingListObj
        };

        return View(bookingViewModel);
    }*/

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Booking booking = new Booking();
        return View("Create", booking);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create(Booking booking)
    {
        List<Booking> bookingsList;

        //BookingList bookingsList;
        /*_cache.TryGetValue(bookingsKey, out bookingsList);
        BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel()
        {
            BookingList = bookingsList
        };*/

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Create", booking);
        }
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(bookingsKey, out bookingsList))
        {
            bookingsList = new List<Booking>();
        }

        bookingsList.Add(booking);
        _cache.Set<List<Booking>>(bookingsKey, bookingsList);

        /*BookingViewModel bookingViewModel = new BookingViewModel()
        {
            BookingList = bookingsList
        };*/

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Booking");
    }
```

BookingViewModel:

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public BookingList BookingList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public BookingsUpload BookingsUpload { get; set; }

    public BookingViewModel()
    {
        Booking = new Booking();
        Bookings = new List<Booking>();
        BookingsUpload = new BookingsUpload();
    }
}
```

Booking Index:

```
    @model WebApplication.ViewModels.BookingViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<br />
<div class="container row p-0 m-0">
    <div class="container col 6">
        <h1 class="text-info">Übersicht aller Buchungen</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container col-3">
        <div class="m-1">
            <a asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info form-control text-white">Erstelle Buchung</a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="w-100 m-1">
                <a asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Export" class="btn btn-info form-control text-white">Export</a>
            </div>
            <div class="w-100 m-1">
                <form asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="custom-file-upload">
                            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
                            Import/validation_bc_fuck_MVC
                        </label>
                        <span asp-validation-for="BookingsUpload.File" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <a asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Import" class="btn btn-info form-control text-white">Import + validation</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-12">
        @if (Model.Booking != null)
        {
            <table class="table table-striped table-borderless table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">

                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Booking.chargeState) %
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Booking.distance) (km)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Booking.connectorType)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Booking.startTime)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => Model.Booking.endTime)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Bookings)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.chargeState)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.distance)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.connectorType)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.startTime)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.endTime)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>Es sind keine Buchungen vorhanden</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-file-upload {
        color: #fff !important;
        background-color: #17a2b8;
        border-color: #17a2b8;
        /*text display: inline-block;*/
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        user-select: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: .25rem;
        transition: color .15s;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    }

    .custom-file-upload:hover {
        background-color: #138496;
        border-color: #117a8b;
    }
</style>
```

So the Import label is the problem because I cant access the File from BookingsUpload to make the span asp-validation-for="File" but with the Import button I managed to go to a different View with only this code below and there the validation works because there I can use the BookingsUpload model:

```
    @model WebApplication.Models.BookingsUpload;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Import";
}

<h1>Import</h1>

<form asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="custom-file-upload">
            <input asp-for="File" type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
            Import
        </label>
        <span asp-validation-for="File" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create view model that will contain `Booking` and `BookingsUpload`, and use it in your view.

```
public class BookingViewModel {
    public Booking Booking {get; set;}
    public BookingsUpload BookingsUpload {get; set;}
}
```

then set those data in your controller's action and in view set model to `BookingViewModel`

```
@model BookingViewModel
// access Booking object view Model.Booking
// access BookingsUpload object via Model.BookingUploads
```

Comment: but I need to have Booking as an IEnumerable<Booking> how can I do that ? also how do I access the Model.BookingViewModel inside the <span asp-validate-for="File" ?

Comment: then you can use `public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings {get; set;}` instead of `public Booking Booking {get; set;}` in `BookingViewModel`.
The File will be `<span asp-validate-for="Model.BookingsUpload.File">`

Comment: 'BookingsViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no accesible extension...are you missing a using directive ?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote as the answer is? please wrote down the code segment that throws the error.

Comment: Do I need to create a Controller for BookingViewModel ?

Comment: BookingViewModel is just a ViewModel. You don't need to create any controller for BookingViewModel, you just need to return view from your action from the controller you had. and use BookingViewModel as model for the view.

You can read more at https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/view-model-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: this seems to have created more problems than before because I've been trying to change my Booking Controller ever since so that I return a View of BookingViewModel but now my list is empty and i can never add anything to it...should i maybe use a partial view or something similar for the Import button ? how does that work ? PS: i can add the Code for the Controller if needed

Answer (score 0):

Add a Constructor to your class where you initialize your objects so it wont be null

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public BookingViewModel()
    {
        Booking = new Booking();
        Bookings = new IEnumerable<Booking>();
        BookingsUpload = new BookingsUpload();
    }
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    public BookingsUpload BookingsUpload { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work... I managed to get past the error shown in the image by changing my BookingController but then I can't access my List<Booking> at all so i never see any entries...

Answer (score 0):

So I finally realized I had a HUGE logical issue. I don't have to use 2 models in the same View. What I did was use a partial to copy the Import button. Like this in the index:

```
<form asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @{
                        await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Import", new WebApplication.Models.BookingsUpload());
                    }
                </div>
            </form>
```

And this is the partial for the Import button:

```
    @model WebApplication.Models.BookingsUpload;

<form asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="Import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="custom-file-upload">
            <input asp-for="File" type="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
            Import
        </label>
        <span asp-validation-for="File" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</form>

<style>
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .custom-file-upload {
        color: #fff !important;
        background-color: #17a2b8;
        border-color: #17a2b8;
        text display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        user-select: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 1.5;
        border-radius: .25rem;
        transition: color .15s;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(1.5em + .75rem + 2px);
    }

    .custom-file-upload:hover {
        background-color: #138496;
        border-color: #117a8b;
    }
</style>
```